# Big O for zigzag merge join?

Tags: google-app-engine, bigtable

What is the Big O for the zig-zag merge join algorithm?

GAE's Big Table uses it, they go into it in these videos:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8
- http://www.bestechvideos.com/tag/zigzag-merge-join

[image]

The reason I ask is that if I understand this example correctly, the Big O will approach O(n) for collections that contain very many matches with only one or the other, but not for both (or all three in this example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [Performance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection#Performance) section of Index Selection article:

> The actual performance depends on the shape of the data. Specifically,
>   the average number of entities considered for each result returned is
>   O(S/R). This indicates that poor performance is likely when many
>   entities match each scan, but few entities match the query as a whole
>   (R is small and S is large).

As article notes this only affects normal indexes. If you want O(log n) speed you should define a composite index.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks so much! Do you mean O(log n) speed as opposed to O(n) speed?